# Trigger to change autoincremented value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, triggers

I have a simple table with tax rates

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TaxRates](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TaxRates] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

If user deleted record I want to not change autoincrementer while next insert.

To have more clearance.

Now I have 3 records with id 0,1 and 2. When I delete row with Id 2 and some time later I add next tax rate I want to have records in this table like before 0,1,2.
There shouldn't be chance to have a gap like 0,1,2,4,6. It must be trigger.

Could you help with that?

Comment: What if you have 0, 1 and 2 and they delete 1. What are your expectations? Do you want the 2 to be changed to 1, or the leave it as is and have the next record inserted as 1? On a side note, aren't you using the Id field in some other tables that would mess the relationship if you tweak Ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to accept gaps or don't use IDENTITY

1. id should have no external meaning
2. You can't update IDENTITY values
3. IDENTITY columns will always have gaps
4. In this case you'd update the clustered Pk which will be expensive
5. What about foreign keys? you'd need a CASCADE
6. Contiguous numbers can be generated with ROW_NUMBER() at read time
7. Without IDENTITY (whether you load this table or another) won't be concurrency-safe under load
8. Trying to INSERT into a gap (by an INSTEAD OF trigger) won't be concurrency-safe under load
9. (Edit) History tables may have the deleted values anyway

Answer (score 0):

An option, if the identity column has become something passed around in your organization is to duplicate that column into a non-identity column on the same table and you can modify those new id values at will while retaining the actual identity field.

turning identity_insert on and off can allow you to insert identity values.